# Run npm install with run scripts options

Tags: node.js, npm

When running `npm install` in the command line you need to wait
that the packages are downloaded , my question if there is option in **one command**
is to run npm install and then npm run some script (not with diffrent command )

for example

if I’ve the script section

```
"scripts" : { "start" : "node server.js" } }
```

and I want to run `npm install run start` ….

is it possible ?

Comment: There's also [**hooks**](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) like `prestart` which execute before `start` automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the different commands by &&:
`npm install && npm run start`

Comment: Thanks 1+, and if I've another scripts like `test`  and `deploy`, how it should work?

Comment: Do the same, it will exit as soon as one of them fails.

Comment: How can I test it with multiple scripts ,can I use scripts that does just echo ?

Comment: @miqdadamirali - can you provide example how to do it ?

Comment: @shopiaT `alias npmir="npm install && npm run start"`